# parsing xml in php returns error

Tags: php, xml

loading xml in php. It is a xml that contains DB query, I want to convert them to real queries:

```
<?php
$myXMLData ="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<createTable tableName='devices'>
      <column name='id' type='INT' autoIncrement='true'>
        <constraints primaryKey='true' />
      </column>
      <column name='name' type='VARCHAR(128)'>
        <constraints nullable='false' />
      </column>
      <column name='uniqueid' type='VARCHAR(128)'>
        <constraints nullable='false' />
      </column>
      <column name='status' type='VARCHAR(128)' />
      <column name='lastupdate' type='TIMESTAMP' />
      <column name='positionid' type='INT' />
</createTable>"
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($myXMLData);`
```

using this classes, first class is table():`

```
class Table
{
    var $tableName;
    var $columns= array();

    public  function set_tableName($name)
    {
        $this->tableName=$name;
    }

    public  function  get_tableName()
    {
        return $this->tableName;
    }

    public function add_column($column)
    {
        array_push($this->columns,$column);
    }

    public function addTableToDatabase()
    {
       $query= "create table ".$this->get_tableName()."(";
        for($i=0;$i<count($this->columns);$i++)
        {
            $name= $this->columns[$i]->get_name()." ";
            $type= $this->columns[$i]->get_type()." ";
            $inc= $this->columns[$i]->get_autoIncrement()." ";
            $null= $this->columns[$i]->get_nullable()." ";
            $key= $this->columns[$i]->get_primaryKey()."<br> ";



            $query.=$name." ".$type." ".$inc." ".$null." ".$key.", ";
        }
        $query=rtrim($query, ",");
        echo $query.")";
    }
}
```

and column() class:

```
<?php

class Column
{
    var $name="";
    var $type="";
    var $autoIncrement="";
    var $nullable="";
    var $primaryKey="";

    ////////////
    public function set_name($name)
    {
        $this->name=$name;
    }
    public function get_name()
    {

        return $this->name;
    }

    ////////////////
    public function set_type($type)
    {

        $this->type=$type;
    }
    public function get_type()
    {

        return $this->type;
    }

    //////////
    public function set_autoIncrement($inc)
    {

        $this->autoIncrement=$inc;
    }
    public function get_autoIncrement()
    {
        return $this->autoIncrement;
    }

    ////////////
    public function set_nullable($null)
    {
        $this->nullable=$null;
    }
    public function get_nullable()
    {
        return $this->nullable;
    }

    ///////////
    public function set_primaryKey($key)
    {

        $this->primaryKey=$key;
    }
    public function get_primaryKey()
    {
        return $this->primaryKey;
    }

    /////////
        public function Column()
        {
            $this->name=null;
            $this->type=null;
           $this->autoIncrement=null;
            $this->nullable=null;
            $this->primaryKey=null;
        }



    //////////

}
```

and this is the index file:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('createTable') as $name)
{
    $table =new Table();
    $table->set_tableName($name->getAttribute('tableName'));

    foreach($name->getElementsByTagName('column') as $col)
    {
        $column=new Column();

        $column->set_name($col->getAttribute('name'));
        $column->set_type($col->getAttribute('type'));
        $column->set_autoIncrement($col->getAttribute('autoIncrement'));

        foreach ($name->getElementsByTagName('constraints') as $const)
        {

            if($const->getAttribute('nullable'))
            {
                $column->set_nullable($const->getAttribute('nullable'));
            }
            if($const->getAttribute('primaryKey'))
            {
                $column->set_primaryKey($const->getAttribute('primaryKey'));
            }
        }
        $table->add_column($column);
    }
    $table->addTableToDatabase();
}
```

result:
create table devices(id INT true false true
, name VARCHAR(128) false true
, uniqueid VARCHAR(128) false true
, status VARCHAR(128) false true
, lastupdate TIMESTAMP false true
, positionid INT false true)

As you can see it must have 5 output for every column but first column is 5 and others are 4. It seems that the error comes from my loops when I want t parse xml into column class. But I can not figure out how to manage to fix my problem

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is critical:

`$column->set_autoIncrement($col->getAttribute('autoIncrement'));`

`autoIncrement` attribute is defined only for first field, so what you have to do is to check if element contains autoIncrement attribute:

`$has_ai = 'false';`

`if($col->hasAttribute('autoIncrement'))`
`$has_ai = $col->getAttribute('autoIncrement');`

`$column->set_autoIncrement($has_ai);`

Or you can update your set method:

```
public function set_autoIncrement($inc)
{
    $this->autoIncrement = (is_null($inc) || empty($inc)) ? 'false' : $inc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I did what you said but in some columns there is not autoincreament or primary key but it sets true for them.what is the problem in your opinion? Result: `create table devices(id INT true false true
, name VARCHAR(128) true false true
, uniqueid VARCHAR(128) true false true
, status VARCHAR(128) true false true
, lastupdate TIMESTAMP true false true
, positionid INT true false true)`

Comment: First of all I need to know for what type of Database you are writing these Create table commands (postgre,mysql,sql)?

Comment: For mysql. If you are thinking about syntax,  I know it should be rectified.

Comment: Instead of true/false for Auto increment, you will have to return `AUTO INCREMENT` and for `nullable` you will have to return `NOT NULL` if `true` and leave it blank if `false`. For primaryKey apply same rule as for `nullable`. You can check mysql create table syntax example on this link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp